# Efficient manner to perform multiple lookups in one custom control

Tags: xpages

I am building a custom control to do a lookup and provide a summary of the status of several items in database.  There are 20 different statuses, and in order to determine the number for each status, I am doing a NotesDatabase.search to count each status.

This was fine when there were only 2 statuses to check, however the business now want all of them displayed. :)

I'm concerned about the time it will take to do the search, and want to do this in the most efficient manner possible.

Things I have taken into account:

- The documents are updated regularly, so I can't really have an agent doing the calcs and  the custom control run a lookup for those static values.  This would mean data is old.
- The results are dependant on the user logged in, doing counts based on their login ID so I can't really have seperate views per person.

Does anyone have a clean suggested solution?

I am about to start testing the 20 searches and will update this with those results, but am expecting it to be very slow.

A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 20 searches you actually might be better off with *ONE* Ajax call. Create a view that is categorized by your status and is collapsed. Then make an Ajax call `...statusview?ReadViewEntries&Outputformat=JSON&count=100`. This will give you the 100 status summary entries with a childcount property.

Would that work for you?

Comment: Thanks - I'm going down this path at the moment, or a variant of it at least.  In fact, I just thought of using a std view, filtered by category name, showing just the status and count.  Then tweaking the display of the view to not show categories as expandable, and removing the detail lines.  If this does not work then I'll go back to the path suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

the other option: instead of @DBLookup you go into the view and just run through it end to end using a navigator. That's pretty fast and should be faster than 20x search.

Of course you could update tallies in the QuerySave event and write it into a user specific in memory profile.

So in your QuerySave you would see what Users are loaded in a ApplicationBean and update those. If a user logs in newly then a search in the database is done into the application bean. When a session expires (Session listener) the entry in the ApplicationBean is cleared out.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to add 20 Status documents, and to update one or more of these documents whenever some condition is met? Each time a document is updated, an agent runs to match with those conditions, in order to update the status.

If there are many updates per day, it's not really efficient.